# PHP function to return only parts of string that contain certain characters?

Tags: php, string

i have a string as follows:

```
$product_req = "CATEGORY-ACTIVE-8,CATEGORY-ACTIVE-4,ACTIVE-6,ACTIVE-9";
```

and i need a function that returns only the numbers preceded by "CATEGORY-ACTIVE-" (without the quotes) so in other words it should return: 8,4 and leave everything else out.

Is there any php function that can do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any php function that can do this?

#### **Yes** you can play around and achieve it with PHP Native functions by writing some code logic. But do it with Regular Expressions (to keep it simple and short).

---

#### Using PHP Functions..

```
<?php
$str = 'CATEGORY-ACTIVE-8,CATEGORY-ACTIVE-4,ACTIVE-6,ACTIVE-9';
$str=explode(',',$str);
$temparr=array();
foreach($str as $v)
{
    if(strpos($v,'CATEGORY-ACTIVE-')!==false)
    {
        $temparr[]=str_replace('CATEGORY-ACTIVE-','',$v);
    }
}
echo implode(',',$temparr); //"prints" 8,4
```

#### Use regular expressions and `implode` it atlast (Preferred way..)

```
<?php
$str = 'CATEGORY-ACTIVE-8,CATEGORY-ACTIVE-4,ACTIVE-6,ACTIVE-9';
preg_match_all('/CATEGORY-ACTIVE-(.*?),/', $str, $matches);
echo implode(',',$matches[1]); //8,4
```

[image]

Comment: `(?<=CATEGORY-ACTIVE-)`

Comment: @zerkms, Modified it.

Comment: @CainNuke, Welcome mate :) Glad to be of help.

Comment: This is correct, but I have two suggestions: 1. the regex can be improved by using lookaround assertion (which zerkms already pointed out), 2. The non-regex way could be improved by changing `strpos()` check to: `strpos($v,'CATEGORY-ACTIVE-') !== 0)`. Cheers!

Comment: @CainNuke, For instance say there is `CATEGORY-ACTIVE-4A5` then `\d+` will fail to match , and that's why I gave a generalized regular expression.

Answer (score 3):

Use [**`Preg_match_all`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and extract the first match

```
$input_lines="CATEGORY-ACTIVE-8,CATEGORY-ACTIVE-4,ACTIVE-6,ACTIVE-9"
preg_match_all("/CATEGORY-ACTIVE-(\d+)/", $input_lines, $output_array);
print_r(join(',',$output_array[1]));
```

**output**

```
8,4
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a lookaround assertion to accomplish this:

```
(?<=CATEGORY-ACTIVE-)(\d+)
```

**Visualization:**

[image: Image from debuggex.com]

**Code:**

```
$str = 'CATEGORY-ACTIVE-8,CATEGORY-ACTIVE-4,ACTIVE-6,ACTIVE-9';
preg_match_all('/(?<=CATEGORY-ACTIVE-)(\d+)/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 8
    [1] => 4
)
```

[**Demo**](http://www.rubular.com/r/MPHlfoNAmY)

Comment: @CainNuke, That exactly matches the digit.

Comment: @CainNuke: `(?<=CATEGORY-ACTIVE-)` checks if the number is preceded by  `CATEGORY-ACTIVE-`. `\d` is a shorthand for the character class `[0-9]` (all the digits). The parens around it denotes a capturing group, meaning we want to *extract* that and store it in the `$matches` array. In simple English: it matches a number **if and only if** it is preceded by the string sequence `CATEGORY-ACTIVE-`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, Feel free to explore the wonderful world of Regex!

https://www.php.net/preg_match

I recommend you do a bit of reading on this yourself as "getting the answers" when it comes to regex is a sin, You learn nothing from it.

I'm not uber experienced with it myself, but it's one of those things that you must learn 'hands on', theory won't cut it here.

Answer (score 0):

in theory it would look like this

$str = 84838493849384938;

preg_match_all(/[8.4]/, $str);

You can also go play around with REgex at this site http://www.phpliveregex.com/

Comment: What do you think `[8.4]` does?

Comment: 8 then nothing exept a new line then 4. basic but works